# use k8s secret from nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes

I've created the following sample program which I need to create secret values

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => (
    res.send("hello from k8s"))
)

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("my secret ---> ", process.env.TOKEN1)
    console.log("server is listen to port", port)
})
```

This is the secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secert1
  namespace: trail
type: Opaque
data:
  TOKEN1: cmVhbGx5X3NlY3JldF92YWx1ZTE=
```

and this is how I connected between of them

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: trail
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1
          image: myimage
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: myenv
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secert1
                  key: TOKEN1
```

When deploying the program I see in k8s logs

```
my secret --->  undefined
server is listen to port 5000
```

What am I missing here ?
in addition assume that I've more than 20 properties which I need to read from my app, is there a better way or just map each of the key value in the secret ?

Comment: In the deployment YAML, you name the environment variable `myenv`.  So either change the code to reference `process.env.myenv` or change the name of the variable in the YAML spec to `TOKEN1`.

Comment: it work! load config and secret [my solution!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990359/k8s-read-secert-from-nodejs-application/68598383#68598383)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` is the key for the env var so with what you have, that should be `process.env.myenv`. You probably instead want to use the `envFrom` option.

Comment: Thanks, can you please answer my second question?  `assume that I've more than 20 properties which I need to read from my app, is there a better way or just map each of the key value in the secret ? `

Comment: I mean put under the `env:` section in the deployment the 20 properties which I need to use in RT?

Comment: Yes, the better way is envFrom

Comment: I took your suggestion as it fits to my requirement however it doesn't works, if you have a time please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990359/k8s-read-secert-from-nodejs-application

Comment: That has nothing to do with envFrom, you used a volume instead.