# k8s read secert from nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I've a nodejs application which needs to read secret in RT

This is the secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secert1
  namespace: trail
type: Opaque
data:
  TOKEN1: cmVhbGx5X3NlY3JldF92YWx1ZTE=
```

I have used a volume to mount the secret as I've many fields that I need to read and I don't want to use the var option.

I've added volume to the deployment as following:

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secret-volume
              mountPath: /etc/secret-volume
      volumes:
        - name: secret-volume
          secret:
            secretName: secert1
```

My question is how should I access the secret from the nodejs app?

I've tried with the following and didnt get any data, any idea?

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/etc/secret-volume', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const content = data;


});
```

Comment: Each `data` property will be a file: `/etc/secret-volume/TOKEN1`

Comment: @Matt - it works , please write it as answer

Comment: @Matt - btw , in case I've from TOKEN1 - TOKEN20 , how should I read them all as each property will be a file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `data` item in a secret will become a file in the `mountPath` of the secret based volume.

To read lots of tokens you can trawl the directory with [`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) and [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options)

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises
const path = require('path')

async function readTokens(token_path) {
  const tokens = {}
  const entries = await fsp.readdir(token_path, { withFileTypes: true })
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (!entry.isFile()) continue
    const buf = await fsp.readFile(path.join(token_path, entry.name), 'utf8')
    tokens[file] = buf.toString()
  }
  return tokens
}

readTokens('/etc/secret-volume').then(console.log).catch(console.err)
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is better then using `env` ? with `secretKeyRef` and put 20 properties inside?what you suggest , what would be better approach?

Comment: couldn't really say either is better. the env variables are probably easier to access in node. the deployment is pretty similar either way ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks, I try the code but it's not working , got errror `(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhan`   any idea?

Comment: any idea ? hint ?

Comment: is it trying to readFile on a directory? maybe test if the entry is a file first

Comment: @BenoOdr I'm also facing the same issue as you've mentioned. How can we solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can read as below.`TOKEN1` is the key from the secret `secert1`

```
var token1_value = fs.readFileSync("/etc/secret-volume/TOKEN1", 'utf8');
```

Comment: Thanks, what If I've more that one TOKEN, like `TOKEN1- TOKEN20` how should I handle it if each token map to a file ?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion what to do in this case, using the `fs.read` 20 times (to read 20 files)  I think it's bad idea, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the secrets as environment variables from K8s this way:

```
          env: 
            - 
              name: MY_SECRET_VARIABLE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secert1
                  key: MY_SECRET_VARIABLE
```

And then in your code, simply use `process.env.MY_SECRET_VARIABLE` to access it.

You can see more details on how to do this here:
https://medium.com/faun/using-kubernetes-secrets-as-environment-variables-5ea3ef7581ef

Comment: Thanks, I understand it however I want to avoid this as I have many fields and I want to avoid it and use volume, can you adopt your answer to volume usage ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very useful solution, I had the same problem and I have solved it like this

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: insertmendoza
  name: sarys-authentications
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sarys-authentications
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sarys-authentications
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sarys-authentications
          image: 192.168.88.246:32000/sarys:authentications
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "500Mi"
              cpu: "50m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000

          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: authentications-config

            - secretRef: <<-- add
                name: authentications-sercret <<-- add

          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volumen
              mountPath: /etc/config/
              readOnly: true

            - name: secret-volumen
              mountPath: /etc/secret/
              readOnly: true

      volumes:
        - name: config-volumen
          configMap:
            name: authentications-config

        - name: secret-volumen
          secret:
            secretName: authentications-sercret
```